# Unable to process the medium or large files using spark 1.3.1 when using stand alone cluster management

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.3.1 to process files along with spark cluster management having 1 worker attached to it.

I am able to process small files and when I try to process the medium or large files I am getting the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 54, 790-GYKGHS1.ad.mdp.com): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:421)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:205)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the executor die/restart? Check the executor log.

Comment: All I found in the long is  ERROR PythonRDD: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error